# Aggregation updating the activities in the group in getstream

Tags: getstream-io

I have a aggregated group called 0 and 1. that is a variable in the field name binary:0.If i put the activity with name of binary:0 it will included in the group binary:0.If i put the activity with name of binary:1 ,it will included in the binary:1.if i update the activity from binary:0 to binary:1, it cannot change the activity form group 0 to group 1. How to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you include more information such as the activity data and the aggregation rule that you are using?

Comment: I'm using the aggregation rule, {{ binary }}. activity data - { 'actor':'krishna', 'verb':'post', 'object':obj,' 'binary':0, 'message':'hi'}

Answer (score 0):

When an activity is updated, existing activity groups are not recreated.

One workaround is to delete the activity and add it back with the updated body.